# Unable to Get Row Count Using ibm_db for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, db2

I have an issue with not able to get the affected rows result from the following

During the debug I notice it always crashes at `conn.querySync(query.sqlUpdate, params);`
Console.log is not showing anything as well.

What did I do wrong here?

**CODE**

```
//imports
const format = require('string-format');


const query = require('../db/query');
const message = require('../common/message');
const constant = require('../common/constant');

var ibmdb = require("ibm_db");
require('dotenv').config();

// access the environment variables for this environment
const database =    "DATABASE=" + process.env.DATABASE  + ";";
const hostname =    "HOSTNAME=" + process.env.HOSTNAME  + ";";
const uid =         "UID="      + process.env.UID       + ";";
const pwd  =        "PWD="      + process.env.PWD       + ";";
const dbport =      "PORT="     + process.env.DBPORT    + ";";
const protocol =    "PROTOCOL=" + process.env.PROTOCOL;

const connString = database+hostname+uid+pwd+dbport+protocol;

function updateContact(params) {
  ibmdb.open(connString, function(err, conn){
    //blocks until the query is completed and all data has been acquired
    var rows = conn.querySync(query.sqlUpdate, params);
    console.log(rows);
  });
}

module.exports.updateContact = updateContact;
```

Comment: Is this really "uery.sqlUpdate" or "query.sqlUpdate"? That could already be the issue.

Comment: that is just the error i made when i copied my codes here

Comment: Could you add the error or call stack? The code looks ok and as copied from the API docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understand what the problem is.
The problem lies in me using the querySync function. This function not return affected row counts.

https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/blob/master/APIDocumentation.md#querySyncApi

The proper way is to use prepare followed by executeNonQuery.

https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/blob/master/APIDocumentation.md#executeNonQueryApi

So from the API, i modify my codes.

```
        ...
        conn.prepare(query.SQL_UPDATE, function (error, stmt) {

            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return conn.closeSync();
            }

            stmt.executeNonQuery(params, function (err, result) {
                if( err ) {   
                    console.log(err);  
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Affected rows = " + result);
                }

                //Close the connection
                conn.close();               
            });
        });
        ...
```